# GridDateTimeColumn I need to set DefaultInsertValue equal to last date that were entered

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table that contains several fields. One of them start Date other one end Date, I need to set DefaultInsertValue for start Date equal to end Date that were entered last time. What is a best way to do it?